# How can I convert an Acrobat XML Form to a "real" PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I am currently using [DynamicPDF Merger for .NET](http://www.cete.com/Products/DynamicPDF_Merger.csp) to fill out the fields in an XML Form produced by Adobe Designer (PDF version 1.6 Acrobat 7)

The XML Form PDF is big (1.5 MB) because each word is a seperate object. We do not want to rebuild the PDF from scratch if possible.

If I use "Print to PDF" then the file is turned into a "real" PDF (not a form) and is then very small (72 KB).

Is there any way we can reproduce this "Print to PDF" on an ASP.NET web server?

Answer (score 4):

I FOUND IT!!!

Ok- Here's what you do.

In the XML PDF click Print
Find the printer named Adobe PDF
Select the location somewhere like the desktop
When it "prints", it will create a "real" Adobe PDF.
You can then paste whatever pages you need into the Adode PDF

Worked for me perfectly!

Comment: Paul you are a lifesaver!!!!! thanks for providing this easy step!  I was looking at other options which didn't work, but this will always work.  THANKS!

Comment: This works, just keep in mind that it will discard information that's not viewable. If you have a XML form PDF and one of the responses cannot fit within the boundaries of the field, the data is still there and it can be highlighted/copied/extracted. However, printing it will discard any overflowing text. So this approach is potentially "lossy"..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to batch-shrink FDF/form-generated PDFs. I kept getting the warning "This PDF document contains Adobe XML form. Such files cannot be optimized". I ran tests with printing instead and it *seemed* to work well (looked identical, significant filesize reduction). However, after further review, Adobe's optimization routines (reasonably) remove anything that isn't being displayed on the page... which means that any response/text that overflowed the boundaries of its display box is simply discarded. This means that long responses get truncated and cannot be retrieved. There may be a way of tuning the print optimization so that it leaves overflow text in place, but I ended up using GhostScript for this which gives me similar levels of optimization without any data loss. The command that I got the best quality:size ratios on was:

```
gs -o 'output-pdf-path.pdf' -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true  -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dColorImageResolution=220  -dGrayImageResolution=220 -dMonoImageResolution=220 'input-pdf-path.pdf'
```

It's also extremely fast, so it had no issues chugging through 100K documents.